# Client.ExecuteAsync loses variable data before saving to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, entity-framework-6, mailgun

I have below code to send email to multiple `email id`s and am using `RestSharp` request and response with `MailGun API`

```
var emodel = model as EmailViewModel;
var context = HttpContext.Current;
var from = "KG <" + emodel.FromEmail[0] + ">";
var client = new RestClient
{
      BaseUrl = new Uri("https://api.mailgun.net/v3"),
      Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("api", WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MGKey"])
};

foreach(var to in emodel.EmailID) 
{
    var request = new RestRequest();
    request.AddParameter("domain",
    "domain.com", ParameterType.UrlSegment);
    request.Resource = "{domain}/messages";
    request.AddParameter("from", from);
    request.AddParameter("subject", emodel.Subject ? ? "No Subject");
    var body = emodel.Message ? ? "Empty Message";
    request.AddParameter("html", body);
    request.Method = Method.POST;
    request.AddParameter("to", to);
    var json = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    client.ExecuteAsync(request, r => {
      var content = json.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,string >>(r.Content);
      if (content != null && r.ResponseStatus == ResponseStatus.Completed && r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) 
      {
          msgId=content.msgID;
      }
      if (msgId != "") 
      {
          using(_db = new DBcontext()) 
          {
              var message = new tblMsg {
                    MDSent = DateTime.Today.Date,
                    MMsg = WebUtility.HtmlEncode(emodel.Message),
                    MMsgStatus = EventTypes.Stored.ToString(),
                    MMsgType = true,
                    MSByID = from,
                    MSByUser = loggedInUser,
                    MSID = msgId,
                    MSub = emodel.Subject ? ? "No subject",
                    MToID = to
              };
              _db.Entry(message).State = EntityState.Added;
              _db.SaveChanges();
          }
      }
      else {
        LogError.LogMessage(r.ErrorMessage, context);
      }
  });
}
```

**EmailViewModel.cs**

```
public class EmailViewModel
{
    public string[] EmailID { get; set; }
    public SelectList Emails { get; set; }

    public string[] Names { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public string[] FromEmail { get; set; }
    public SelectList FromEmails { get; set; }

    public bool HasAttachment { get; set; }
    public string AttachmentPath { get; set; }
    public int AttachmentCount { get; set; }

    public string Subject { get; set; }
}
```

The problem over here is when I send an email to multiple ids, because of `client.ExecuteAsync` line which is inside `for-loop`, it will fetch `async` response multiple times and store it in `content` and before `message` record saves into database, it gets replaced with the next `async` response from `API` and hence only one record gets saved in database. Is there any mechanism in C#, wherein I can hold variable message value until its saved to database? I tried using `lock` on `content` variable, but it did not help.. Hoping to find some help.

Comment: What is the type of `client`? We've only got half the story here. Can you reproduce this in a [mcve] that doesn't involve anything extraneous? (Given that you create a new request for each iteration, it looks like it probably *should* be okay...)

Comment: @JonSkeet.. Added complete code.. Also the necessary class.. Hope this will be sufficient.. Let me know if not please..

Comment: @JonSkeet Yea, the idea for having `for-loop` was same, to create new request, but then because of `client.ExecuteAsync`, it does not accept for `response` to behave as `for-loop`.. Hence, the above issue..

Comment: Well it's more complete, but it's far from minimal, and we still don't know *which* `RestClient` class this is. One from somewhere in the framework? A third party library? Can you demonstrate this without using the database?

Comment: Have you tried creating a new `RestClient` on each iteration of the loop? Maybe *that's* not set up to handle multiple concurrent requests...

Comment: @JonSkeet **[This is the one the RestClient](http://restsharp.org/)**.. I would like to create a `demo`, but are there any site where I can create one.. Sorry, because am unaware of such site except `DotNetFiddle`, . Is it possible to create there?. In the mean time I will try with creating `RestClient` for each iteration..

Comment: You don't need to create an online version. You should just create something we can copy, paste, compile and run, if at all possible. But *please* think about what information answerers are likely to want when you ask a question - there was no indication at all that you were using RestSharp.

Comment: Sorry for that @JonSkeet. I would keep this in mind.. I tried with creating `RestClient` for each iteration but even that did not help.. Am afraid, by creating the demo, I might also need to give api key, which should be secret right? Please let me know if there is any other way I can do it..? Can we implement some `lock` mechanism here? I've tried it but may be not the right way I did it.. Could you please let me know if there is anything I can try more?

Comment: Well it's still not clear what's actually happening. You say "it gets replaced with the next async response" - what *exactly* do you see? Again, I'd urge you to take the database side out of this... can you observe the effect just by logging?

Comment: @JonSkeet Can we have a TeamViewer Session, if you don't mind?

Comment: No, Stack Overflow isn't an interactive debugging session. You need to come up with suitable diagnostics and clarity so that this question doesn't just help you, but is useful for future readers to.